# css before do not align to the correct div

Tags: css

I am creating a drop down but the font awesome down arrow do not display inside the correct div. You will see in the below code the font awesome for the "fbox" div shows at the end of the "sbox" div.

The HTML looks like this

```
 <div class="fbox">
    <select class="search_dropdown" name="search_dropdown" id="search_dropdown">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="sbox"> 
  <input type="text" class="search_filter" id="search_filter" placeholder="Search for names..">
</div>
```

And the CSS looks like this

```
.fbox select {
   background-color: #F8F8F8;
   color: #33333;
   padding: 12px;
   width: 250px;
   border: none;
   font-size: 16px;
   -webkit-appearance: button;
   appearance: button;
   outline: none;
   border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
 }

 .fbox::before {
   content: "\f13a";
   font-family: FontAwesome;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
 }
```

The jsfiddle of this ticket is. https://jsfiddle.net/us40hw16/1/

Comment: something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/wy3kfLct/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to align any `absolute` element, you must set `position: relative` to its parent.

- You need to set `position: relative` to `fbox` in order to align the
  `font-awesome` icon to select box.
- change `appearance` and `-webkit-appearance` to `none` in `.fbox select` to hide its default arrow.
- Add `pointer-events: none` in `.fbox::before` so that your drop-down
  can work on click of arrow
- Additionally, you must set `position: relative` to `.sbox` to prevent
  alignment issues of icon in future

```css
.search_wallview {
    overflow: visible!important;
}

.search_intro {
  margin-top: 30px;
  background-color:#005959;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  margin-left: -50vw;
  margin-right: -50vw;
  height: 600px; 
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  background-size: cover; 
}

.search_position {
    position: relative;
    padding: 4px 0 10px 0;
    max-width: 800px;
  margin: 250px auto 0 auto;
}

.search_inputgroup {
   position: relative;
   display: flex;
   width: 100%;
}

#search_filter{
  font-size: 16px; /* Increase font-size */
  padding: 12px 20px 13px 40px; /* Add some padding */
  border: 1px solid #ddd; /* Add a grey border */
  border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
  width: 100%; /* Full-width */
}

.sbox {
  width: 60%; /* Full-width */
  position: relative;
}

.sbox::before {
  content: "\f002";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 20px;
  color: #333;
}

.search_dropdown{
   display:inline-block;
   width: 40%; /* Full-width */
   height: 47px; 
}

.search_result {
    background-color:white;
    color:black;
      padding: 4px 0 10px 0;
      max-width: 790px;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
    margin:auto;
}

.search_line {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.search_line:hover {
   background-color: #EFEFEF;
}

/* Drop down css  */
.fbox {
  position: relative;
}
.fbox select {
  background-color: #F8F8F8;
  color: #33333;
  padding: 12px;
  width: 250px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
}

.fbox::before {
  content: "\f13a";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 3px;
  color: #4d4d4d;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="search_wallview">
<div class="search_intro">  
  <div class="search_position">
    <div class="search_inputgroup">
     <div class="fbox">
        <select class="search_dropdown" name="search_dropdown" id="search_dropdown">
          <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
          <option value="saab">Saab</option>
          <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
          <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="sbox"> 
      <input type="text" class="search_filter" id="search_filter" placeholder="Search for names..">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  <div id="search_result" class="search_result">line</div>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

link to [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/z06ykgch/1/)

Comment: Thanks for help. If I add "position: relative;" to sbox. Then the sbox icon is not at the complete Right of the text box. I am trying to see the reason. Any further help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you use absolute positioning, it positions itself relative to the nearest parent that is not statically positioned. You need to make .fbox `position: relative` so the :before element aligns to the right of it.

You also need to make the icon a colour other than white so it can be seen.